# Why do midwesterners say "the cancer"?

Tags: history, dialects, north-american-english

I was watching the TV show [*Fargo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fargo_%28TV_series%29), which takes place in rural Minnesota. Most of the locals on the show speak with a recognizable midwestern accent, and there are some regionalisms that are common. The one that I noticed most was how when some of the characters were talking about another person they knew, they said *he has **the** cancer*. Most of the English-speaking world does not put an article before the names of most diseases — we would say *he has cancer*.

I believe that many of the early settlers in this part of America were from Scandinavia, and it heavily influenced the dialect and accent. Is this phrasing quirk related to this heritage?

Comment: You can have *the measles*, *the flu*, *the mumps*. Why not *the cancer*?

Comment: Article usage is idiosyncratic, and I'm sure you're right in suggesting historic influences when it comes to diseases. Generally, I'd say, 'the' is optional with flu and plague, and virtually mandatory with 'the Black Death' and 'the French disease' (but not 'German measles').

Comment: @PeterShor Good point. Although you can have _the flu_, but we don't usually say _the influenza_.

Comment: I wonder if they're just more consistent, using the article before all diseases, rather than having it differ on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Was it whispered? There was a historical prejudice in using the term 'cancer'.  In fact, obituaries mentioned every cause of quietus but a death due to cancer. The term 'the cancer' may be an outgrowth of this prejudicial sentiment.

Comment: I am fairly sure that they're not consistent, and this is just an idiosyncrasy where *cancer* has moved to the list of diseases that take *the*. You would have to get somebody who knows Scandinavian languages to say whether it originated there; I suspect not.

Comment: **No, that is *not* a “recognizable midwestern accent” you hear in the movie *Fargo*.** Speaking only of the United States now, not Canada, it is an accent unique to the Superior part of this country ranging from North Dakota east across the top swath of Minnesota and Wisconsin, and including the Upper Peninsula of Michigan.  This accent is totally distinct from anything you will ever hear in the midwestern burgs of Milwaukee, Chicago, Gary, Des Moines, or Detroit, let alone anywhere at further remove from [the big lake they call *Gitche Gumee*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Superior).

Comment: @tchrist I wasn't sure what to call that region of the country. It's not all of the midwest, but it's not just a specific state, either, so I couldn't call it a Minnesota accent.

Comment: [That particular accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fargo_(film)#Accent) is explained pretty completely at the cited reference. We Wisconsinites have been known to call it a Scandihoovian accent.

Comment: There IS a TV show. It just started several weeks ago. It's based on the movie. See the Wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: @tchrist - for goodness sake, Tom. It *is* a show. The fourth episode aired this week. It's not by the Coen brothers (though they have exec. pro. billing), but is loosely based on the movie (more like *No Fargo for Old Men*).

Comment: This is not a midwestern accent.  I live in the midwest.  Northern Minnesota, the Dakotas, Wisconsin, Michigan, and so on have influence from the midwest but also a heavy influence from Canadian dialects.  I don't ever hear anyone say the cancer.

Comment: @Barmar - note, she answered *yuh. Leukemia.* not *the lukemia*. It's spotty and it's TV. A lot of Minnesotans have said the accent is bad. It's still an interesting show.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a supposedly "dialectal" usage in a TV series which is itself based on a movie. The Coen brothers, who are involved in both, are imho notorious for blurring the boundaries between *actual/historical* linguistic forms, and invented forms which merely suit their artistic purposes. It's a [very rare usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died+of+the+cancer%2Cdied+of+cancer&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20the%20cancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20cancer%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I love your close vote reason, but there is a little flaw in it - the Coen Brothers are **not** involved in it - and it sounds like a peeve against *them*. It's not their fault, no matter how lowly one's opinion is of them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a supposedly "dialectal" usage in a TV series, not actual English.

Comment: @medica: Wikipedia says [the Coen brothers ... who serve as executive producers of this series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fargo_(TV_series)). As to me "peeving" against them - no way! I think they're brilliant! I know [this blogger is talking about the movie](http://dialectblog.com/2011/05/29/the-fargo-accent/) rather than the TV spinoff, but I completely agree with him where he says *"I was a huge fan of Fargo, although I can see how the film’s signature dialect is a bit of a fiction."* Ditto with the marvellous Mattie in *True Grit*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - **OMG**!! You're quoting *Wikipedia*?? Please, know that the only thing the Coen Brothers had to do with this show was to give them permission to use the name and setting/context. The **price** of that was getting listed as EPs. I, too, love the earlier CB stuff. Which is why I read about the show. (The CB said the same in an interview.)

Comment: @medica: I don't generally watch TV series, so I haven't seen the Fargo one, and I don't expect to. But even if they have no editorial influence at all, it seems likely to me that since weird "dialectal accents" and unusual vocabulary choices are a feature of *most* Coen movies (and *Fargo* in particular) that would very likely be reflected in the spinoff regardless. I don't object to it in the slightest, but I wouldn't use such sources to inform myself about *real* language usage, any more than I would watch Hollywood war movies to learn about modern history.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - [Wall Street Journal](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2014/04/16/why-billy-bob-thornton-jumped-on-fxs-fargo/), [Vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2014/05/fargo-briefcase-cameo-explainer.html)

Comment: @medica: Thanks for the link. It won't induce me to watch the series (I got suckered into watching *Breaking Bad* over a year ago, and I was *seriously* pissed off when I realised I'd have to wait several months to watch the concluding episodes! :). But your link has reminded me that I haven't seen *The Man Who Wasn't There*. I have complete faith that when I do, I'll enjoy it.

Comment: **People seem to be confusing *dialect* and *accent* here.** Matters of variation of syntax, idioms, and vocabulary are different from matters of variation in pronunciation, intonation, and phrasal prosody. An intrusive article where otherwise unexpected has nothing to do with pronunciation, and thus nothing to do with accent; it is a matter of syntax, an observation which clearly brands this question as one dealing with *dialect*, not with *accent*.

Comment: I've lived in Michigan (which I consider to be part of the Midwest) for most of my life and have never heard "the cancer".  I usually hear "a cold", "the flu", and "pneumonia" (without an article), and I have therefore given up any attempt to understand the usage of articles with names of diseases. (Both "cancer" and "influenza" are used without articles, even though the latter means the same as "the flu".)

Comment: @tchrist: I assume most if not all of us here realise the two terms are distinct (though in many contexts I'm inclined to think of *accent* as a subset of the variations contained within a *dialect*). But the thing is everybody knows they're very closely associated. The exaggerated accent is actually a *feature* of creative fiction such as *Fargo* (both movie and TV series). The script-writers can't back up the accent with too much non-standard *vocabulary* that the audience won't understand (regardless of whether it's accurate or not), but they can play games with syntax, article usage, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm no expert on the area, but I'm pretty sure I've heard similar phrasing in Prairie Home Companion skits.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm certainly not an "expert" in any formal sense, but I think I'm right in saying we have more "regional" dialect/accent variation in the UK than the US. And because we're in a much *smaller* area, most Brits probably hear a greater spread of these variations purely because *we've been there* or met the people. So perhaps we're more likely to notice when "scripted/acted" versions either exaggerate or simply "get it wrong" out of ignorance or carelessness (or simply for artistic effect, providing it does actually *work*, as opposed to simply making the audience groan in despair).

Comment: Don't think people talk that way just because it's on a TV show. I'm from rural northern Minnesota. and I don't think I've heard the term. I haven't watched the show, but I can say that when people from that area watch the movie, it's mostly to laugh at how wildly inaccurate their attempt at our accent is.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a stereotype, although stereotypes usually have some basis in fact. Boston accents on TV are similarly exaggerated, but not too far off.

Comment: Possible solution: It was "[ball] cancer" first, which was deemed inappropriate after screening and consequently redubbed with a filler; the type--ball, lung, breast ...--does not matter, though of course it wasn't pancreas. This holds water iff injury is more offensive than bad grammar, that can be convincingly chalked up to an odd regiolect. Especially if screened with the main audience from the midwest, if the so called bible belt is as uppity as the stereotype has me believe. I'm sorry that this *is* offensive.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question.  They normally don't.

I live in the Midwest.  I have had several friends and relatives over the past 10 years have cancer.  I have never heard of "the cancer" from anyone, including friends and hospital staff.

I don't doubt your reference.  What I doubt is your connection to Fargo and the dialect of the show and the Midwest.  On the show they speak much more with a Canadian/local accent. It is something that you would hardly find in Illinois, Indiana, Missouri, Iowa, Arkansas, Nebraska, Kansas...

Comment: Be warned that some of those states you’ve named would not be recognized as “midwestern” by someone from Duluth or Green Bay.

Comment: @tchrist - I understand that the term means slightly different things to different people.  I could have added Ohio, Kentucky, Tennessee, possibly Oklahoma.  Maybe I could have left a state or two off.  I don't think anyone from the midwest would consider Fargo the midwest (even if it is labeled so on some map).  Certainly there are different dialects and for sure there is heavy Canadian influence, eh.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd The US Census Bureau considers the Midwest to be Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Michigan, Minnesota, Missouri, Nebraska, North Dakota, Ohio, South Dakota and Wisconsin. I've never before heard anyone suggest that any of Arkansas, Kentucky, Tennessee and Oklahoma are in the Midwest.

Comment: Different parts of the Midwest speak dramatically different dialects. There's no reason to expect somebody in Indiana to say *"the cancer"* just because several people in Minnesota say it. But Minnesota is still generally considered part of the Midwest.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - we are talking about dialects not census bureau reports.  I was listing the states with the Midwest dialects.  As I mentioned those states (ones you listed) are borderline - because you will get both Midwest and Southern dialects.  The other states you mentioned, the Dakotas, Minnesota, Michigan, Wisconsin... they tend to have different accents/dialects (Michigan probably different from the rest - more East coast) so I would not include them in a question.  I am sure there are quite a few opinions on this, this is just mine.

Comment: The term "midwest dialect" does not necessarily imply that it's used throughout the midwest. Analogously, what's known as a New Englang accent is mostly found in Maine and Vermont, although it has some things in common with the Boston accent (they both drop trailing Rs), which is not the same as the South Boston accent ("wicked pissah").

Comment: @Barmar - I don't see how I can answer the question without generalizing.  I understand it isn't 100% and there are one-offs all over the place.  Simply saying, been in the Midwest a lot of my life, been around a lot of people with cancer, and have never heard it.

Answer (score 4):

Cancer is not the only disease to which a definite article has been attached. The malady caused by the bacterium *Yersinia pestis* is often referred to as *the plague*, and one of its other descriptors, *the Black Death*, is another example.

My sense is that one of the reasons for attaching a definite article to the name of a disease may be that it reflects the notion people have of it as a mysterious and fated phenomenon ("the big C"); an irresistible and usually fatal affliction against which people are powerless, either because it is their destiny to succumb to it and/or because there is no known or guaranteed antidote or remedy.

However, that's only an unsubstantiated hypothesis, and it doesn't explain why not every much-feared and hard-to-cure or -prevent disease has acquired the definite article.

The likelihood of a Scandinavian origin for the use of the definite article when referring to cancer is not very plausible, for a couple of different reasons:

1) Among the main Scandinavian languages, only in Swedish is the usual word for *cancer* 'cancer':

- Danish (DA): **kræft**, with **cancer** being a parallel but less-often-used term
- Norwegian (NO): **kreft**
- Swedish (SV): **cancer**

2) In most Scandinavian languages, the definite form of a noun is indicated by the addition of a suffix (typically *-en* or *-et*; e.g. the Danish word for *liver* [the organ] is 'lever', and *the liver* is 'leveren'). But when someone is described as suffering from cancer -- or indeed any disease -- this form is not the one used.

For example, *He has liver cancer* would be rendered as follows (the literal translation in all cases is "He has cancer in the liver"):

DA: Han har kræft/cancer i leveren

NO: Han har kreft i levern

SV: Han har cancer i levern

The bald description *He is suffering from cancer* follows the same pattern (in all cases it translates literally as "He suffers of cancer"):

DA: Han lider af kræft/cancer

NO: Han lider av kreft

SV: Han lider av cancer

Comment: "Cancer is not the only disease to which a definite article has been attached." This misses the point of the question. Cancer *doesn't* usually have the definite article and the question is asking why a particular speaker *does* use the article when referring to "the cancer"

Comment: @David Richerby - The OP's second paragraph makes it obvious that he believes the use of the definite article with *cancer* is not restricted to a single speaker, but is widespread in the Minnesota region. I don't know whether the OP's impression is accurate or not; if you had read my response carefully, you'd have noticed that I didn't make any assumption either way about the accuracy of the OP's perception, but that I *did* reference a couple of examples where the definite article *is* attached to a disease. Your comment misses the point of my answer.

Answer (score -3):

If it is real, it's just a common over-generalisation error rather than an L1 interference. It seems that people assume that since you can get the flu, the plague etc. that one can "get" *the cancer. It's not just midwestern North Americans that I've heard this from, and whether or not people are parroting this usage just for humor's sake is another question.

The difference in usage lies in the fact that you *contract* the plague and influenza as they are communicable diseases. Cancer is not. It is caused by cancerous cells in the body, whereas the others are transmitted to the victim from another host via a virus or other pathogen. You *contract* the flu (referring to the Influenza Virus specifically, distinguishing it from many other viruses), but you *develop* cancer. You would only use the definite article if you were referring to specific cancerous cells - "the cancer cells in my liver..."

Comment: You can "have the shakes", which are not communicable. And you used to be able to "have the rheumatism", again not communicable. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+the+rheumatism%2Chave+the+shakes%2Chave+rheumatism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20rheumatism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20shakes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20rheumatism%3B%2Cc0). Furthermore, for many diseases which *are* communicable, you don't use the definite article.

Comment: Umm, not exactly. You also *contract* Chicken Pox, Herpes, strep throat, encephalopathies, meningitis, bronchitis, pneumonia, HIV and almost innumerable other illnesses which have no article preceding them. There is no *rule*, rhyme, nor reason to it.

Comment: @petershor Firstly, the formal usage of "the shakes" refers not a disease you contract, but a condition that you develop; Delirium tremens. Note that saying "*the Delirium tremens" is obviously incorrect. The definite article in "the shakes" is attached to the verb "shake" and creates a noun-phrase, "The Shakes".

Comment: Secondly, which @medica is helpfully pointing out for me, all of those are referring to conditions caused by or inside something else. The Chicken Pox virus causes Chicken Pox ad infinitum. Bronchitis is developed due to an infection, but you cannot catch bronchitis from someone else.

Comment: @Tea.Geek.nz - that's nonsense. We don't use an article for things *inside* or *contracted* or *from something else.* **"conditions caused by or inside something else"** is pure nonsense.

Comment: @media I've heard (and had) "the chicken pox".

Comment: You state that cancers are never caused by infection. This is incorrect. For instance, it has been shown that cancer of the cervix (plus several other cancers of the genital region) is often the result of infection with certain strains of the human papilloma virus (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hpv ). For information about cancers caused by other infective agents, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infectious_causes_of_cancer . I'm afraid this undermines the linguistic point you were making in your answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - so have I. I also had *the* measles, but not *the* mumps. It doesn't matter. Some people use the article (I've never said *the cancer*), some don't. There are no rules, and it varies from person to person.